# Log URL and load page time in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm looking for a way to write to a log the URL and page load time in Symfony2 in prod envoirment and in prod server.

I need to know that URLs are taking longer to load as we have a problem of overload on the server and development mode localhost I do not see anything unusual.

I wonder if any request AJAX or just that with the increase of simultaneous users on the server requirements increase too and you have to make use of some powerful cache technology.

The values that are currently handle 300 simultaneous users consume 240 to the microprocessor load.

Does anyone can tell me how to do that log with page load time and URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your web-server to the log request urls, load times, etc ...

Here's an example for nginx:

```
http {
    log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"'
                             'rt=$request_time uct="$upstream_connect_time" uht="$upstream_header_time" urt="$upstream_response_time"';

    server {
        access_log /spool/logs/nginx-access.log upstream_time;
        ...
    }
}
```

Taken from the nginx documentation chapter ["Logging and Monitoring"](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/logging-and-monitoring/).

We're using a similar log-configuration in our devevelopment environment, too. (using syslog instead of logfiles and logstash/kibana to gather/visualize)

Comment: Thanks, in another way to do, better than mine :)